# Special arrangement of 16 cards

Tags: combinatorics

This puzzle is from Martin Gardner.

You are given 16 cards containing all aces, kings, queens and jacks from a standard deck of cards. Can you arrange them in a 4x4 grid such that each row and each column contain all four suits as well as one of each face value? **Bonus question:** in addition to the row and column constraints, can you also make each main diagonal contain all four face values and all four suits? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I misunderstood something, but I think this works (?)

> [image: Row 1: heart ace, diamond queen, club jack, spade king. Row 2: spade jack, club king, diamond ace, heart queen. Row 3: diamond king, heart jack, spade queen, club ace. Row 4: club queen, spade ace, heart king, diamond jack.]

Comment: Wow that was super fast! I think it works.